# How can I open a query in datasheet mode in a subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform on a mainform. I want to have it open a query in datasheet view.
I tried:

```
Me.subform.Application.DoCmd.OpenQuery "xxx"
```

But it just opens the query in the background, not inside the subform.

I know that by creating a form bounded to this query, then I can change de subform's SourceObject to open it inside the subform. However I have here many different queries, I just want to find a simpler way.

EDIT: Maybe something like: `Me.subform.OpenQuery "xxx"`, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the sub form's Source Object to a query name instead of a form name. In the property sheet, it should look like Query.XXX.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't set the Query prefix.